# Change radio/checkbox to drop down box with minimal changes to PHP coding?

Tags: php, html, internationalization, checkbox, drop-down-menu

Solution: thanks to the suggestion from @Guarav I was inspired and FINALLY came up with the solution, please tell me what you guys think of my solution and any ways I can improve this further. And yes, thats a challenge. Bet you can't.

```
<?php 

function selectLang($a,$b,$c,$d,$e){

echo "<div id='menu2' style='width:250px; margin-left:-40px;'> <ul class='double'>

<li style='background:#333333; color:white;'>Demonstration Play Feature</li>";
echo "<form method='post'  action=''>";
echo "<li><select name='languages[]'>";
while(list(,$values1) = each($c) AND list(,$list) = each($b) AND list(,$list2) = each($e)) {
echo "<option name='languages[]' value='$values1' />" . $list . "</option>";
echo "<option name='languages[]' value='$values1' />" . $list2 . "</option>";

}
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Send' name='poll' /></li>";

echo "</form>";
echo "<li><b>" . $d ."</b>";
echo "<button onclick='JavaScript:changeSheets(1)' style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/def.png); width:40px; height:40px; border:none;'></button>";
echo "<button onclick='JavaScript:changeSheets(2)' style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/def1.png); width:40px; height:40px; border:none;'></button>";
echo "<button onclick='JavaScript:changeSheets(3)' style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/def2.png); width:40px; height:40px; border:none;'></button>";
echo "<button onclick='JavaScript:changeSheets(4)' style='background-image:url(/misc/FYP/images/def3.png); width:40px; height:40px; border:none;'></button></li>";

echo "</ul></div>";
}

$values = array("English","Japanese","Chinese","Hungarian","Arabic","French","Russian","Thai","Korean","German");

$lang_eng1 = array("English","Japanese","Chinese","Hungarian","Arabic");
$lang_eng2 = array("French","Russian","Thai","Korean","German");

$lang_chi = array("English","Japanese","Chinese","Hungarian","Arabic");
$lang_chi2 = array("French","Russian","Thai","Korean","German");

$lang_jap = array("英語","日本語","中国語","ハンガリー語","アラビア語");
$lang_jap2 = array("フランス語","ロシア語","タイ語","韓国語","German");

$lang_rus = array("Английский","Японский","Китайский","Венгерский","Арабский");
$lang_rus2 = array("Французский","Русский","Тайский","Корейский","German");

$lang_kor = array("영어","일어","중국어","헝가리어","아라비아어");
$lang_kor2 = array("프랑스어","러시아어","타이어","한국어","German");

$lang_ger = array("Englisch","Japanisch","Chinesisch","Ungarisch","Arabisch",);
$lang_ger2 = array("Französisch","Russisch","Siamesisch","Koreanisch","German");

$h_eng = "Select Your Language";
$h_chi = "Select Your Language";
$h_jap = "言語の選択";
$h_rus = "Выбрать язык";
$h_kor = "언어 선택";
$h_ger = "Wählen Sie Ihre Sprache vor";

$h2_eng = "Change the Colour Scheme";
$h2_chi = "Change the Colour Scheme";
$h2_jap = "カラースキームの変更";
$h2_rus = "Изменить фон";
$h2_kor = "색채 설계";
$h2_ger = "Ändern Sie den Farbe Entwurf";

?>
```

On my website I have a change language feature with radio boxes, if one is clicked then the language of the website will change. This looks like:
[image]

The code for what is produced above is:

```
    <?php 

function selectLang($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g){

echo "<div id='menu2' style='width:400px; margin-left:-40px;'> <ul class='triple'>

<li style='background:#333333; color:white; width:400px;'>Demonstration Play Feature</li>";
echo "<form method='post'  action=''>";
echo "<li style='width:400px;'>";
while(list(,$values1) = each($c) AND list(,$list) = each($b) AND list(,$list2) = each($e) AND list(,$list3) = each($f) AND list(,$list4) = each($g)) {

echo "<input type='radio' name='languages[]' value='$values1' style='padding:3px;' />" . $list;
echo "<input type='radio' name='languages[]' value='$values1' style='padding:3px;' />" . $list2;
echo "<input type='radio' name='languages[]' value='$values1' style='padding:3px;' />" . $list3;
echo "<input type='radio' name='languages[]' value='$values1' style='padding:3px;' />" . $list4 . "<br />";

}

echo "<input type='submit' value='Send' name='poll' /></li>";

echo "</form>";

echo "</ul></div>";
}

$values = array("English","Japanese","Chinese","Hungarian","Arabic","French","Russian","Thai","Korean","German");

$lang_eng1 = array("English","Japanese","Chinese","Hungarian");
$lang_eng2 = array("French","Russian","Arabic");
$lang_eng3 = array("Thai","Korean","German");
$lang_eng4 = array("Korean","German");
$lang_chi = array("English","Japanese","Chinese","Hungarian","Arabic");
$lang_chi2 = array("French","Russian","Thai","Korean","German");

$lang_jap = array("英語","日本語","中国語","ハンガリー語","アラビア語");
$lang_jap2 = array("フランス語","ロシア語","タイ語","韓国語","German");

$lang_rus = array("Английский","Японский","Китайский","Венгерский","Арабский");
$lang_rus2 = array("Французский","Русский","Тайский","Корейский","German");

$lang_kor = array("영어","일어","중국어","헝가리어","아라비아어");
$lang_kor2 = array("프랑스어","러시아어","타이어","한국어","German");

$lang_ger = array("Englisch","Japanisch","Chinesisch","Ungarisch","Arabisch",);
$lang_ger2 = array("Französisch","Russisch","Siamesisch","Koreanisch","German");

$h_eng = "Select Your Language";
$h_chi = "Select Your Language";
$h_jap = "言語の選択";
$h_rus = "Выбрать язык";
$h_kor = "언어 선택";
$h_ger = "Wählen Sie Ihre Sprache vor";


?>
```

However, I dont want the radio/check boxes anymore. Is there anyway i can change this to a drop down box which will still work exactly the same?

thank you for any suggestions.

**Edit:
@Gaurav
I tried you suggestion with the final code which looked like:

```
   <?php 

function selectLang($a,$b,$c,$d,$e){

echo "<div id='menu2' style='width:250px; margin-left:-40px;'> <ul class='double'>

<li style='background:#333333; color:white;'>Demonstration Play Feature</li>";
echo "<form method='post'  action=''>";
echo "<li>";
while(list(,$values1) = each($c) AND list(,$list) = each($b) AND list(,$list2) = each($e)) {

echo "<input type='radio' name='languages[]' value='$values1' />" . $list;
echo "<input type='radio' name='languages[]' value='$values1' />" . $list2 . "<br />";
}
***echo "<li>";
echo "<select name='languages[]'>";
while(list(,$values1) = each($c) AND list(,$list) = each($b) AND list(,$list2) = each($e) AND list(,$list3) = each($f) AND list(,$list4) = each($g)) {

echo "<option value='$values1'>" . $list ."</option>";
echo "<option value='$values1'>" . $list ."</option>";
echo "<option value='$values1'>" . $list ."</option>";

}
echo "</select>";
echo "</li>";***

echo "<input type='submit' value='Send' name='poll' /></li>";


echo "</form>";


echo "</ul></div>";
}

$values = array("English","Japanese","Chinese","Hungarian","Arabic","French","Russian","Thai","Korean","German");

$lang_eng1 = array("English","Japanese","Chinese","Hungarian","Arabic");
$lang_eng2 = array("French","Russian","Thai","Korean","German");

$lang_chi = array("English","Japanese","Chinese","Hungarian","Arabic");
$lang_chi2 = array("French","Russian","Thai","Korean","German");

$lang_jap = array("英語","日本語","中国語","ハンガリー語","アラビア語");
$lang_jap2 = array("フランス語","ロシア語","タイ語","韓国語","German");

$lang_rus = array("Английский","Японский","Китайский","Венгерский","Арабский");
$lang_rus2 = array("Французский","Русский","Тайский","Корейский","German");

$lang_kor = array("영어","일어","중국어","헝가리어","아라비아어");
$lang_kor2 = array("프랑스어","러시아어","타이어","한국어","German");

$lang_ger = array("Englisch","Japanisch","Chinesisch","Ungarisch","Arabisch",);
$lang_ger2 = array("Französisch","Russisch","Siamesisch","Koreanisch","German");

$h_eng = "Select Your Language";
$h_chi = "Select Your Language";
$h_jap = "言語の選択";
$h_rus = "Выбрать язык";
$h_kor = "언어 선택";
$h_ger = "Wählen Sie Ihre Sprache vor";

$h2_eng = "Change the Colour Scheme";
$h2_chi = "Change the Colour Scheme";
$h2_jap = "カラースキームの変更";
$h2_rus = "Изменить фон";
$h2_kor = "색채 설계";
$h2_ger = "Ändern Sie den Farbe Entwurf";


?>
```

But it only showed a drop down box, it didnt have any values in the drop box. But its a start thanks. any ideas on how we can develop this further?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code in function and  let me know  it works or not.

```
echo "<select name='languages[]'>";
while(list(,$values1) = each($c) AND list(,$list) = each($b) AND list(,$list2) = each($e) AND list(,$list3) = each($f) AND list(,$list4) = each($g)) {

echo "<option value='$values1'>" . $list ."</option>";  // change value and text ($list) according to you
echo "<option value='$values1'>" . $list ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: HEHE, I worked it out. again, please refer to the description where youll see the suggestion.

Comment: Also i have given you best answer cos your answer inspired the solution

Comment: you are still using radio buttons, do you still need them?